# BsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bsonDocument) - Id field of child object causes exception

Tags: c#, mongodb, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I have a class A and a class B and C

```
public class A  
{ 
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<B> Children {get;set;}
}
public class B
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Foo {get;set;}
    public double Bar {get;set;}
}
public class C 
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    //This property will hold a serialized version of Class A.
    //The scenario requirement is that it can hold any arbitrary BsonDocument of different types
    public BsonDocument Properties {get;set;} 
}

var instanceOfClassC = collection.Find(...).First();

var data = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<A>(instanceOfClassC.Properties);
```

This last line causes the exception bellow.
If I add ignore BsonElement to the Id property of class B it works fine.
But I need that Id property!

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in  MongoDB.Bson.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while deserializing the Children property of class NameSpace.A: Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class NameSpace.B.
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in  MongoDB.Bson.dll

The problem seems to be that the property B.Id is actually stored as "Id" in MongoDb since it's "serialized" to a BsonDocument before storage. The same pattern otherwise always works perfect, but than MongoDb will transform Id => _id at write time.

Requirement: class C.Properties contains arbitrary kinds of other valid class types and cannot be changed to type A in class declaration. It works smooth - except that nested Id property!

**Update:** Found a brutal hack solution: Rename all "Id" properties in the BsonDocument to "_id" before shipping of to MongoDb. Then deserialization works as expected. I do this with string replace of a json 
json.Replace("\"Id\"", "\"_id\"")

**Anyone has a better solution?**

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner solution would be:

```
public class A  
{ 
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<B> Children {get;set;}
}
[BsonNoId] // this solves the problem
public class B
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Foo {get;set;}
    public double Bar {get;set;}
}
```

You can also do this without an attribute, using the BsonClassMap:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<B>(cm =>
{
    cm.SetIdMember(null);
});
```

Which is usful if the types you are mapping are from a different library